# How can I detect if mouse is down outside of window in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

As the titles says i wonder if it is possible to detect if the mouse button is down. I tried putting this code in my app delegate.m but with no success.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"hello world!");
}
```

A quick google search showed me that this method only works inside of NSWindows. However, there most be some way to detect if mouse position is pressed, and if so; how can i do it?

Comment: You should consider if you really care about a mouse-down event or if what you're actually interested in is loss of active status for your app or key/main status for one of your windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`:

define in your control:

```
id mouseEventMonitor;

-(id)init{

    mouseEventMonitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDownMask | NSOtherMouseDownMask)
                                           handler:^(NSEvent *event){

        NSLog(@"theEvent->%@",event);

        //here you will receive the all mouse DOWN events
        if (event.modifierFlags & NSCommandKeyMask)
        {
          NSLog(@"theEvent1->%@",event);
        }else{
          NSLog(@"theEvent2->%@",event);
        }

    }];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Any way read the Cocoa Event Handling Guide: link:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this, to detect if command key and mouse button is down: NSLeftMouseDownMask & NSCommandKeyMask?

Comment: No! you have to check inside the handler:     mouseEventMonitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:((NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDownMask | NSOtherMouseDownMask))
                                           handler:^(NSEvent *event){
        if (event.modifierFlags & NSCommandKeyMask)
        {
           NSLog(@"theEvent1->%@",event);
        }else{
           NSLog(@"theEvent2->%@",event);
        }
                                               
       
                                               
    }];

Comment: maybe you can help me with this question too: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581908/how-can-i-freeze-all-interaction-with-other-windows)

Comment: Hey again. It seems like your code sometimes doesn't work. however it works 80 % of the time. Any ideas what could be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa **Event Monitors** are the way to go.
You can use them to track pretty much every kind of mouse event outside of your view hierarchy.

Check out the documentation in the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/eventoverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html) for information on how to use them and similar topics here on SO like

- [In what way a view or a window could know that mouseDown outside itself in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930336/in-what-way-a-view-or-a-window-could-know-that-mousedown-outside-itself-in-xcode?rq=1)
- [How do i detect keystrokes using objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142464/how-do-i-detect-keystrokes-using-objective-c/3142485#3142485)

Answer (score 0):

Although you mention `mouseDown` in your question and have accepted an answer that describes how to set up a monitor, as far as I can tell from the rest of the question, you don't actually need an event that fires when the mouse button is pressed, but instead just want to check if a mouse button is *currently* pressed.

[`NSEvent` has a class property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1527943-pressedmousebuttons) you can use for this:

```
[NSEvent pressedMouseButtons]
```

This returns the indices of the currently pressed mouse buttons:

> A return value of 1 << 0 corresponds to the left mouse button, 1 << 1 corresponds to the right mouse button, 1<< n, n >=2 correspond to other mouse buttons.