# How can i "freeze" all interaction with other windows?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This question might seem kind of odd. Basically I'm trying to make a menubar application. When the user presses command, I want to make so that you can't interact with other apps running (write/select/click etc).

Im using this code to detect if command and mouse button is pressed:

```
mouseEventMonitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask ) {
         if (event.modifierFlags & NSCommandKeyMask)
                                                                       { 
    // "Freeze" all other apps.
    }
    }];
```

When I use this on the desktop it works find, however, using this xcode in safari or xcode causes huge lag because they conflict with my app. I also tried adding a invisible window behind this. But, when I did so the mouseEventMonitor will not work because it only work for events outside of the app.

I hope i explained this well enough.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I am don't really understand your question, but for invisible background window (inside your app) you can try use `LocalMonitor` instead `GlobalMonitor`:

```
mouseEventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDownMask | NSOtherMouseDownMask) handler:^NSEvent *(NSEvent *event) {


NSLog(@"theEvent->%@",event);

return event;
}];
```